# Issues in calling generic method through reflection with a delegate parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, delegates

I've been messing around with this for over an hour and just cannot seem to get it right. Here's one of the exceptions I am getting:

> Error: Object of type `System.Func1[System.Object]` cannot be
>   converted to type `System.Func1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable1[System.Object]]]`.

Basically I have a generic factory method which looks like this

```
ReturnItem<TResult> CreateOutput<T, TResult>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> postBack,
    Processor manager) where TResult : class;
```

and I am trying reflect into, but the `Func<IEnumerable<T>>` is causing me problems. Here's the code I have in trying to call it:

```
var infer = Factory.CreateReturnInference(); //Keypair value (type, type) is NOT an NormalOutputFactory in this instance
Func<object> callBack = () => subTypes;

var toRun = Factory.GetType()
            .GetMethod("CreateOutput", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .MakeGenericMethod(infer.Key, infer.Value)
            .Invoke(Factory,
                new object[] {callBack, Manager}) as
            ReturnItem<object>;
```

The keypair value returned from `Factory.CreateReturnInference` is used to specify the generic parameters, and just to provide clarity on its implementation (warning very ugly code, violates open-close amount other stuff :)):

```
public KeyValuePair<Type, Type> CreateReturnInference()
    {
        return this is NormalOutputFactory
            ? new KeyValuePair<Type, Type>(typeof (object), typeof (Log))
            : new KeyValuePair<Type, Type>(typeof (IEnumerable<object>), typeof (Enum));
    }
```

The general question is: When calling a generic method through reflection how do I specify a `Func` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not specifying the `Func<T>` parameter properly. In other words what you're passing to `CreateOutput` method is of incorrect type. When you do:

```
MakeGenericMethod(infer.Key, infer.Value)
```

the type parameters for method

```
ReturnItem<TResult> CreateOutput<T, TResult>(Func<IEnumerable<T>> postBack, ...)
```

you're passing are `typeof(IEnumerable<object>)` and `typeof(Enum)`. Because you do

```
return new newKeyValuePair<Type, Type>(typeof(IEnumerable<object>), typeof(Enum));
```

Hence the `CreateOutput`method you're trying to create has a signature like this:

```
ReturnItem<Enum> CreateOutput(Func<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>> postBack, ...)
```

In other words, `T` becomes `IEnumerable<object>` and `TResult` become `Enum`. But the `Func` argument you pass to invoke the constructed generic method `callback` is defined like this:

```
Func<object> callBack = () => subTypes;
```

### Your solutions are:

1) Either change signature of `callback` like this:

```
Func<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>> callBack = () => subTypes;
```

2) Or change the parametric types for the generic method by adjusting your key value pair function.

```
Func<IEnumerable<object>> callBack = () => subTypes;

public KeyValuePair<Type, Type> CreateReturnInference()
{
    return ... new KeyValuePair<Type, Type>(typeof(object), typeof(Enum));
}
```

I think the 2nd one is what you want, but I cant be sure.

Comment: Or you may even make CreateOutput method accept "Func<T>" as argument and change callback and CreateReturnInference accordingly.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. I sorted it by tweaking the the method that returns the keypair. I have an interesting thought though: Suppose I have an object held by an abstract reference like this: `IEnumerable<<IEnumerable<object>>`. I have no doubt that this can be treated as an `object` type. But, can it be treated like this `IEnumerable<object>`? It would seem to make sence it could, because you could cast each one of those objects to an IEnumerable

Comment: @William I am not sure I get you. Yes you can transform your IEnumerable<<IEnumerable<object>> to an IEnumerable<object> like this: "IEnumerable<object> = IEnumerable<<IEnumerable<object>>.SelectMany(x => x);" if that helps. It's called flattening.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort it out by changing the return of the KeyValuePair to this:

```
public KeyValuePair<Type, Type> CreateReturnInference()
{
    return this is NormalOutputFactory
        ? new KeyValuePair<Type, Type>(typeof (object), typeof (object))
        : new KeyValuePair<Type, Type>(typeof (IEnumerable<object>), typeof (object));
}
```

Still not too happy about doing this, but solves the issue